# C How to create a Makefile for a MPI program?

Tags: c, linux, makefile, mpi

I have 3 C files, all of them form one C program. One of them is a MPI file, it is called mpi.c, the others are read.c and write.c. I don't know how to include mpi.c in my Makefile, here's got I got so far (and it's wrong):

```
   all: program

   program: mpi.o read.o write.o
        mpicc mpi.o read.o write.o -o program // I think this line is wrong

   mpi.o: mpi.c
        mpicc -o mpi.o mpi.c

   read.o: read.c
        gcc -c read.c -o read.o

   write.o: write.c
       gcc -c write.c -o write.o

   clean:
       rm -f write.o read.o mpi.o program core *~
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think it's this line:

```
mpicc -o mpi.o mpi.c
```

and that it should be

```
mpicc -c mpi.c -o mpi.o
```

or simply

```
mpicc -c mpi.c
```

The way it stands, it's attempting to compile mpi.c alone into a program called mpi.o, when mpi.o should simply be an object file.